# SQL Server Check if Value repeats in next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check if the row value repeats in next row. If it does than the Ticket is still open and if it is closed then I need to show value in Closed column.

In example below, Ticket 55 is open from May 1st to May 7th so each day I am showing it Open in Open Column and on May 7th the Ticket is closed so I show it as closed

```
         Ticket    Open  Closed 
5/1/2019    55      1   
5/2/2019    55      1   
5/3/2019    55      1   
5/4/2019    55      1   
5/5/2019    55      1   
5/6/2019    55      1   
5/7/2019    55      1   1
5/8/2019    60
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       (case when date = max(date) over (partition by ticket)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as closed
from t;
```

It would appear that you simply want `1 as open`.

If the ticket values can repeat, use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ticket = lead(ticket) over (partition by ticket order by ticket)
             then 0 else 1
        end) as closed
from t;
```

Comment: My problem is I cannot use Max because Ticket 55 can reopen again after 2 weeks. In that case it is a new issue.              If Ticket 55 is open every consecutive day then it is a same issue.

Comment: @Raj . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask, and your question does not mention that this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `ticket` and he date column you showed no name for aren't nullable, you can use `lead()` to get the next ticket ID for a ticket where the records are ordered by the date column you showed no name for. If that is null that means there is no follow up. Also using `lead()` you can check if the date of the next record is the next day.

```
SELECT ...
       CASE
         WHEN lead(ticket) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket
                                 ORDER BY <your anonymous date column>) IS NULL
               OR lead(<your anonymous date column>) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket
                                                           ORDER BY <your anonymous date column>) <> dateadd(day, 1, <your anonymous date column>) THEN
           1
       END closed,
       ...
```

Replace `<your anonymous date column>` with the name of the date column.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2012 or later you can use `LEAD()`. Here is a sample :

I have found next ticket number via `LEAD()` function partitioned by TicketNumber. If it returns a value that's mean the ticket still not closed. If it is null ticket is closed.

```
SELECT    T.TicketDate
        , T.TicketNumber
        , CASE WHEN LEAD(T.TicketNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY T.TicketNumber ORDER BY T.TicketDate ) IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '1' END [Open]
        , CASE WHEN LEAD(T.TicketNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY T.TicketNumber ORDER BY T.TicketDate ) IS NULL THEN '1'ELSE '' END Closed
FROM Ticket T
```